# Intero doesn't find Paths-module when using cabal data files

Tags: haskell, emacs, cabal, intero

When I use the data-files feature of cabal, it generates a `Paths_pkgname.hs` module that lives in the `dist/` folder.

However, intero is unable to find this file (or generate it on its own), and I can't find any means to pass an option to hint at its position.

Note: Somewhere else (on SO?) I picked up the trick when using ghci to make a dummy `only-for-ghci/Paths_.hs` that is only brought into scope through `:set -ionly-for-ghci` being set in `.ghci`. This won't apply for intero though, as its invocation in `intero.el` specificcally instructs it to ignore the `.ghci` file.

Answer (score 1):

I was only building my project using cabal and nix. It turns out that because Intero is stack-centric, building the project with `stack build` does indeed put a `Paths_..` module in a place where Intero searches.